# Wi-fi signal info of devices attached to a router

Tags: wifi, signals, router

Is there a way to access the signal info of the devices that are attached to a wireless router? I was thinking that maybe that information is given in the router homepage, but my netgear router only gives me the IP and MAC addresses of the attached devices. Also, in case that this isn't possible with my router (DGN2000), are you aware of another device that gives that kind of information (even if it needs custom firmware to display it).

I want to make an app that collects the attached device signal data and I am stuck.

Comment: Maybe if the devices support [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) and your stack has some support for it...

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution. Any router that can run on dd wrt firmware can access that data by navigating to "status" and then "wireless" in the router page. Another (and expensive) solution is the Apple Airport router, that gives that data via the airport utility.